# Why do metal finders not use any sensors other than search coils?

Tags: coil, magnetics, mems, metal-detector

I was wondering why metal finders do not use any other sensors to recieve the magnetic signal instead of search coils.

I have been looking at MEMS sensors used as digital compasses, for example.

As far as I understand even s simple HMC5883L will be more sensitive than most search coils - receive winding, hence allow further depth search - wouldn't it?

Comment: What are you searching for? Ferromagnetic objects? metal objects? Or magnets? This sensor is usually used to sense *static magnetic fields*, like earth's field, passively.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately there are not so many physical phenomena that are unique to metals and which can be observed through soil and also started through the soil, if the phenomenon happens only under external excitation. Only those phenomena are valid which happen at reasonably low intensity in the soil materials. The soil unfortunately is more or less conductive and absorbs light effectively. The remaining non-atomic physics phenomena are magnetic fields (static ones and fields which are caused by induction currents.) Induction also happens in the soil, but its intensity is far lower than what's caused by metal objects. That's because the metals have much higher conductivity.  Coils are our practical way to cause induction. In theory we could have moving magnets instead, but that's mechanically complex and causes strength problems at high frequencies - and coils would still be needed to detect field changes caused by induction.

Static fields could be detected by other means like Hall or more advanced sensors, but using them is also most practical if one tries use a coil to make a field which cancels the existing static field.

Trying to generate atomic physics effects or elementary particle reactions is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: "In theory we could have moving magnets instead" -- granted, good luck monitoring a tiny (~ppm?) change in torque, or inertia, but it could in principle be entirely mechanical. But then, what would we use to spin it (and likely sense it too), anyway? Motors, that contain coils... point taken. 8-)

Answer (score 6):

What else would they use? Neutron activation? :^)

...Okay, that would be pretty cool, actually, obvious hazards aside. :)

Anyway.  Just a regular compass, doubtful; HMC5883L specifies only mG resolution.  But a fluxgate magnetometer (sensitive down to µT, µG even) might detect iron at modest depths.

You won't be sensing anything else; even many iron alloys have minimal magnetic signature (e.g. stainless steel), and precious metals, essentially none.  You will also be sensing a lot of rock, as magnetite is abundant, and unevenly distributed.

You'll also be sensing large contiguous structures, like steel buildings and railroad tracks; obviously, the latter will change more gradually over distance, but it's worth adding for perspective.

Am curious where you got your figure from, as far as receive coil sensitivity; at some 100s kHz typically, a return error of some nT could easily be measured, I think(??).  It's not really fair to compare field strengths between AC and DC, though.

Answer (score 6):

> even simple HMC5883L will be more sensitive than most search coils

Maybe more sensitive than the simplest of search coil circuits - the kind that run on two transistors or a single op-amp or something just as basic.

Otherwise - no. Professional metal detectors that are sold for industry use, as opposed to weekend treasure hunters, use a combination of sensors, and magnetic field detection uses fluxgate sensors, orders of magnitude more sensitive than anything you can buy in a chip.

Answer (score 5):

Coil-based metal detectors use excitation field to detect the eddy currents induced in conductive materials. They can detect any metal, and even distinguish them by the conductivity. Because of the high frequency, most MEMS magnetic sensors are too slow be used to detect the eddy current pulse, so coils are used.

Measurement of static magnetic fields, on the other hand, can only detect metals that have their own magnetic field. Mostly just iron and steel, though nickel and cobalt would be detectable in large enough amounts.

In larger scale, magnetometer surveys are used to locate ore deposits. This relies on the abundance of iron ores in Earth's crust, the location of which will also give clues to other ore veins and rock types.

Answer (score 3):

Ground penetrating radar is possible, but limited resolution and expensive.

Gravity gradient and gravity have been tried, and they can work fairly well if you have a deposit the size of an aircraft carrier and some fairly fancy instrumentation- gravity is a very weak force.

Electric fields are not too useful because soil is conductive.

I suppose you could try seismology. Whack the ground and see what comes back, but again limited resolution. It's used in mineral exploration.

Magnetic fields have the advantage they can pick up on the relatively high conductivity of metals in a sea of more-or-less conductive material. The same principle is used from aircraft for geophysical surveying for the extractive industries.

Ferromagnetic objects are generally not very valuable (certainly they are not made of precious metals), so of less interest to the treasure hunters. Even if they are not magnetized if they are large they can distort the earth's field and be detected. Maybe they could find a tin can filled  with something or other.

Comment: Ground impedance tomography does work as you're interested in changes of the conductivity - you're making a map of impedance anomalies. But the spatial resolution is poor.

Comment: Add soil resistivity to that (five helpers, each with a probe, and a rotating switch on the meter). Also NMR, there was a Scientific American article on that in the 70s and somewhere on YouTube somebody tries it.